# How to pull multiple Congressional vote records via XML import and compare/average

Tags: xml, excel

I'm trying to compile a Congressional voting record but am having trouble organizing the data. Here is my process to this point...

1. Import mapped XML data from House Clerk. No problem here.
2. Combine the votes (let's say there are three votes we're looking at) according to the Member of Congress.
3. Compute the grade using weighted averages (weighting based on importance to the organization). No problem here either.

Here is my problem...

My problem is combing the votes into one sheet. You see, Members of Congress come and go (for a host of reasons). This makes it difficult (at least with my somewhat limited Excel proficiency) to match up names and votes. Currently I am mapping the names, states, and party (columns A-C) of the Members from Xml data for the most recent vote. This accomplishes having an accurate up-to-date listing. XML data for votes 1, 2 and 3 (columns D-F) is then imported; however, Members who have departed Congress (or in one case, this world) are throwing things off in terms of the rows matching up. As such, the voting average (column G) is inaccurate.

What is the most elegant, efficient solution to...

1. Always have an up-to-date listing of Members of Congress in column A?
2. Import voting record (one column for each vote) for specific bills and according to the corresponding Member listed in column A?

Comment: Have congress add districts to the voting record.  A database is only as good as the person who designed it.

Comment: Simply listing your requirements and asking for help is not a good way to ask a question on this site. Please see [Why is "Can someone Help me" not an "actual" question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work.

Comment: I was pretty clear in explaining exactly what _I_ am doing ("Currently I am....however.... and what it is not working...") Perhaps you mean my request is still too broad? Are pictures preferred? I'm happy to post the actual workbook if that's acceptable practice here.

Comment: jdweng,

"Have congress do _______..." I'll assume that was a tongue-in-cheek commentary on the lack of productivity in Congress and thank you for the clever poke.

The inputs aren't changing.

Comment: Actually, jdweng, I could also map and import Members' unique-id. Still, this doesn't immediately solve my problem of having the imported voting records match up with the correct corresponding Member.

Comment: Does the unique-id include bits indicating districts?

Comment: It does not; however, I can pull the district info as well, yes. Why do you ask? Again, what I am trying to do is have the Member listed in column A and pull all the voting information for a number of bills across in the row. What I have tried is importing the list of Members, then importing each vote roll in the columns to the right of the Member list. As mentioned though, the rows don't always line up nicely because there are departures between votes.

Comment: By the way, here is the roll call vote XML schema (if that helps give you a sense of what information is included) - [link](http://xml.house.gov/rollcall/vote.xsd).